# Populating JComboBox with multiple informations

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox

I'm in a position, where I have to populate a JComboBox with names from my users (5 users). When the user clicks the name in the JComboBox I want to retrieve the UserID of the user, not their actual name due some of them may be the same, and make a SQL query with their UserID as WHERE filter.

I have the all the users informations temporary stored in an Object, retrieved by a MySQL database.

How can I code a way to put more informations in the JComboBox, but only show the actual name to the user?

I hope this make sense, elsewhere feel free to ask questions.

Thanks in advance,
Jesper.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `User` object that contains the name and user id with appropriate getters (and setters if required).  Add these to the combo box.  Use a `ListCellRenderer` to define how the `User` object is actually renderer.

See [How to use comboboxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/). It explains that you need to follow two steps to implement a proper solution:

1. use a custom renderer
2. use a custom `KeySelectionManager` so you don't break default combo box functionality when using a custom renderer